# Phantom No-Diff Unstaged Changes that can't be "Replaced with HEAD" in Eclipse Git Staging

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

My Git Staging in Eclipse reports touched files that have **no diffs** and that I never touched at all. When I click **Replace with HEAD Revision** it **does nothing** and the checkouts remain.

As soon as I delete and re-clone the Git repository and re-import the Git project, I see that the **>** icon (modified) immediately appears on these files in the recreated project, even though they weren't modified by me.

This is while ignoring whitespace. See pictures. Whitespace isn't the issue -- even if it was, my "Replace with HEAD" command should be executed and it isn't, it's just ignored.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Line ending differences?

Comment: No, this is while ignoring whitespace. I'll clarify in the OP.

Comment: _Ignore White Space_ means not to show(!) differences of white space in the _Compare Editor_, but they are there and in Git those are changes. If you use Git also on the command line, in the _Git Staging_ view you have to hit the _Refresh_ button. Your Eclipse looks pretty old and maybe also your EGit is outdated too. Please upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following option which worked for me.

For the files appearing in Unstaged changes (Files which dont have any change,but appears in unstaged changes) during Commit, **Right click on the file - Click on Assume unchanged option**. Refresh or restart the eclipse and try to  commit any file without making any changes and check any files appearing in Unstaged changes.

Hope this will work :)

Comment: Did not work for me.